# Error al enviar peticiones del frontend al backend en UBUNTU( aws ) net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, angular, aws, nginx

Subi un proyecto a un EC2 de Amazon Web Services, el backend se encuentra corriendo en el puerto 3000 correctamente. El frontend esta corriendo con NGINX, pero al intentar ejecutar un servicio que se conecta con el backend lanza el error como se muestra en la imagen:

> polyfills-es2015.39e6a31b601b9b3913c6.js:1 POST http://localhost:3000/Inicio/Persona net::ERR_FAILED

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Xms.png)

Este es el codigo del servidor, trabaja en el puerto 3000

```js
server.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port'));
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json()); // Reconocer el formato JSON
app.use(cors());

app.use('/Inicio/Persona',require('./route/persona.route'));
```

El backend se ejecuta correctamente en el puerto 3000
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkGaa.png)

Y el frontend se comunica mediante un servicio :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Persona } from '../modelos/persona';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders }from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PersonaService {

  headers=new HttpHeaders();

  selectedPersona: Persona;
  personas:Persona[];
  readonly URL_API='http://localhost:3000/Inicio/Persona';
  readonly URL_API_changePass='http://localhost:3000/Inicio/Persona/changePass';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.selectedPersona=new Persona();
  }

  postPersona(persona:Persona){
    return this.http.post(this.URL_API,persona);
  }
```

Y este es el archivo de configuracion en NGINX

```js
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name ong.com;

  # angular app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/front-end;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema está en la url a la que Angular apunta `http://localhost:3000`

Angular se ejecuta en el cliente por lo que ese `localhost` será la máquina local y no el servidor del backend.

Cambia el dominio `localhost` y reemplázalo por el dominio o la IP del backend.